# What is the different between resource pools and workload groups in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, resource-governor

In SQL server one can use resource pools and workload groups, what is the difference between them? Why should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Resource Governor Concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb933866.aspx)

> - **Resource pools**. A resource pool, represents the physical resources of the server. You can think of a pool as a virtual SQL
>     Server instance inside of a SQL Server instance.
> - **Workload groups**. A workload group serves as a container for session requests that have similar classification criteria. A workload
>     allows for aggregate monitoring of the sessions, and defines policies
>     for the sessions. Each workload group is in a resource pool.